# Drop rows that do not contain a string within a value using pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to use python pandas to drop rows in a spreadsheet that do not contain "CAT" within the "Equipment" column.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import warnings
import xlrd

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

file_name = input("Enter File Name: ")
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)


for i in range(len(df["Equipment"])):
    if "CAT" in df["Equipment"][i]:
        print (df["Equipment"][i])
    else:
        df.drop([i])

df.to_excel("new_mp.xlsx")
```

The script prints out the correct values in the terminal but does not drop the rows in the new spreadsheet "new_mp.xlsx". Can someone point me in the right direction?

Example Data:

```
Equipment
CAT 259B3 1818 OE Skid Steer 2011 CAT
T-14 Towmaster Trailer 3124 OE Trailer 2008
CAT 938M Loader RPO RENTAL 2017 CAT 938M
Rental Water Truck 55571 Rental Water Truck international water truck
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a loop here; you can do this with `str.contains`:

```
v = df[df["Equipment"].str.contains('CAT')]
print(v)
                                  Equipment
0     CAT 259B3 1818 OE Skid Steer 2011 CAT
2  CAT 938M Loader RPO RENTAL 2017 CAT 938M
```

Or, use `query` with `engine='python'`:

```
v = df.query('Equipment.str.contains("CAT")', engine='python')
print(v)
                                  Equipment
0     CAT 259B3 1818 OE Skid Steer 2011 CAT
2  CAT 938M Loader RPO RENTAL 2017 CAT 938M
```

Finally, write to disk:

```
v.to_excel("new_mp.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to filter the rows.

```
df[df['Equipment'].apply(lambda x: 'CAT' in x)].to_excel("new_mp.xlsx")
```

**Edit:**

Alright, let me explain this inside out :

`lambda x: 'CAT' in x` takes as input x and returns True if 'CAT' is in x.

Now the `df['Equipment'].apply` method will invoke the `lambda` function mentioned above on every value of the series. The result will be a boolean array which is then passed on to the `df` as boolean mask.

Hope I didn't overdo it.

Comment: I don't believe this accounts for when `'CAT'` is *contained* in the cell value, i.e., it only considers when the entire cell value *equals* `'CAT'`; can you modify your answer?

Comment: Yea, missed the contains part. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This worked! would you mind giving me a brief explanation as I am trying to learn more and use it on some other projects